# Why does Table.FromList() fail on this trivial conversion from integers?

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-2016

Consider Microsoft's first example for [Table.FromList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-fromlist).  Invoking it in the trivial query

```
let
    result = Table.FromList({"a", "b", "c", "d"}, null, {"Letters"})
in
    result
```

results in a table that looks like

```
| Letters |
+---------+
| a       |
| b       |
| c       |
| d       |
```

Substituting numbers for letters results in the query

```
let
    result = Table.FromList({1,2,3,4},null,{"Integers"})
in
    result
```

which produces the error

> Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value 1 to type Text.
>
> Details:
> Value=1
> Type=Type

I expected the table

```
| Integers |
+----------+
| 1        |
| 2        |
| 3        |
| 4        |
```

1. How do I get the expected table?
2. What is happening that is causing this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's written in the function description:

> By default, the list is assumed to be a **list of text values that is split by commas**.

if you convert the list to table using the UI, you can notice that the default splitter is replaced:

```
let
    Source = {1,2,3,4},
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)
in
    #"Converted to Table"
```

so the solution to your problem is

```
let
    result = Table.FromList({1,2,3,4}, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"Integers"})
in
    result
```

Answer (score 0):

Because numbers and text are stored differently in computer memory.
You can't perform calculations with text, so 1 as a number has to be treated different from 1 as a symbol, to computers. Remember that a computer is just a machine and not a person, it lacks common sense sometimes. The solution is that you need to put quotation marks around those numbers. When the computer sees quotation marks it will know you are talking about the symbols

Try this:

```
let
    result = Table.FromList({"1","2","3","4"},null,{"Integers"})
in
    result
```

Comment: Converting these to text doesn't help me because the integers causing the error correspond to an ID column of type `Int64.Type` from another table.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
letList={1..4},
result =Table.FromList(List.Transform(List, each Text.From(_)), null, {"Numbers"})
in result
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. I had not taken that into proper consideration